# CDockablePane - Sliding - Redrawing

Tags: mfc, mdi, dock, cview

I have an MFC MDI application using the new MFC Feature Pack. I have a CDockablePane that has the autohide option enabled. My CView driven class takes a lot of time to be drawn. The problem I am facing is that when the pane is sliding (to autohide or auto appear), each step in the sliding makes the CView redraw itself! This is making the sliding takes a lot of time and the application appears very heavy. Is there a way to avoid these unnecessary redrawings and draw the CView driven object only once?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CDockablePane::m_bDisableAnimation = TRUE;
```

on your mainframe constructor.